# Using the recommended python parse.com library to wrap their REST api, why does the following occur

Tags: python, rest, parse-platform

Code:

```
for k in dir(parse_rest.User):
    print parse_rest.User[k]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/ntresch/Development/webapp/appcode.py", line 53, in <module>
     for k in dir(parse_rest.User):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'User'
```

The [docs](https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy) show the following:

```
#Users
#You can sign up, log in, modify or delete users as well, using the User object. You sign a user up as follows:

u = parse_rest.User.signup("dhelmet", "12345", phone="555-555-5555")

#or log in an existing user with

u = parse_rest.User.login("dhelmet", "12345")
# Once a User has been logged in, it saves its session so that it can be edited or deleted:

u.highscore = 300
u.save()
u.delete()
```

I really want to know what all I can do with the user object.  This behavior seems wonky.

Comment: Do you have a local file `parse_rest.py` file?

Comment: based on the documentation you don't use it directly. You need to create a `User` class that inherits from `parse_rest.Object`

Comment: @Cfreak I think you're mistaken. I pasted the EXACT code sample from their site and they say to use the User attribute of the parse_rest object somehow, as in my paste.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah I do I have it installed locally.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My colleague laughed at me for using that library. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a case of (at the time) out-of-date documentation, fixed as of [3/11/2013](https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy/commit/5884cffddee2c0801e654e1cd8eb5fe2f576d98c). The way to access the User class is not `parse_rest.User` but:

```
from parse_rest.user import User
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is don't use that library.  My colleague has one we home rolled checked into our source tree and we're planning on releasing one.  When we do I will post a link here for completeness. :)

Comment: Once you do, please let us know at feedback@parse.com so we can get it up on the third party libraries page.